# What should the number of trials $n$ be?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is the question:  Strings of Christmas tree lights were designed so that if any one of the bulbs failed, none of the bulbs would light up. Each string has places for $12$ bulbs.  I'll fill them up with bulbs left over from last Christmas. I have a large box of bulbs but $5$% are burned out. I select at random from the bulbs in the box to fill up the strings of lights.

If $X =$ number of good bulbs in a string of $12$. What is the probability that a string will light up?

I know the formula to solve the problem, but I'm not sure what $n$, which is the number of trials, should be.

Comment: What is the formula to solve the problem?

Comment: What plausible choice of values do you have?

Answer (score 2):

The string will only light up if all 12 bulbs are in working condition.  The probability that the first bulb you pull is in working condition is $0.95$, since 5% of the bulbs don't work.  If your box is big enough, we can assume that the second bulb will also work with probability $0.95$.  (In reality, we've now removed 1 working bulb, which means the percentage of bulbs that work is slightly lowered.  This is typically ignored.)  So the probability that both bulb 1 and bulb 2 work is $0.95\cdot 0.95=(0.95)^2$.  The probability that the first three bulbs all work is $0.95\cdot 0.95\cdot 0.95=(0.95)^3$.  Can you now see how to compute the probability that all 12 bulbs work?